# Algorithm caption size reduction

Tags: algorithm2e

Wants to reduce the caption size of the Algorithm. `\scriptsize`, `\footnotesize` works for the body of the algorithm but not for the caption/title.

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}    
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}  
\usetikzlibrary{fit,matrix,positioning, decorations.pathreplacing,calc,shapes,arrows,shadows,patterns}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\newdimen\zerolinewidth

\begin{document}    
\begin{algorithm}           
    \scriptsize
    \caption{Algorithm title}       
\end{algorithm} 
\end{document}
```

Also, how to change 'Algorithm' to 'Algo'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Form the package documentation:

> `\SetAlgorithmName{algorithmname}{algorithmautorefname}{list of algorithms name}` 
>   which redefines name of the algorithms and the
>   sentence list of algorithms. ... omissis ... Second argument is the
>   name that `\autoref`, from `hyperref` package, will use.
>
> `\SetAlCapFnt{<font>}` sets the font used for {algorithm: } in caption
>   of algorithm (default is set to `\relax`).
>
> `\SetAlCapNameFnt{<font>}` sets the font used by caption text. Default
>   is `\relax` and text is kept as it is.

```
\documentclass[10pt,journal,compsoc]{IEEEtran}   
\usepackage[ruled,vlined,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\SetAlCapNameFnt{\scriptsize}
\SetAlCapFnt{\scriptsize}
\SetAlgorithmName{Algo}{Algo}{List of Algorithms}
\begin{document}  
\begin{algorithm}           
    \scriptsize
    \caption{Algorithm title}       
\end{algorithm} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Buon guorno! Our answers crossed ;-)

Comment: @marmot You're always faster than me!

Comment: Don't worry, I can remove my answer....

Comment: @marmot You're a gentleman... ops gentlemarmot